# parallel transport and local frame

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold $M$, and a smooth curve $\gamma: I \to M$. We know how to define the parallel transport along the curve, denoted by $\tau_t$. Now at point $T_{\gamma(0)}M$ we can take a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, we have $\tau_t(v_1), \ldots, \tau_t(v_n)$. Those form a basis at $T_{\gamma(t)}M$, because parallel transport is a linear isomorphism.

Now let $W$ be a vector field on $M$, $W_\gamma(t)= \sum c_i(t)\tau_t(v_i)$. Is it true that $c_i(t)$ must be smooth?

Comment: If your vector field is smooth, the coefficients are.

Comment: Why should that be true assuming the smoothness of the vector field?

Comment: Keith: Can you do this exercise? Suppose $v_1(t),\dots,v_n(t)$, $t\in I$, form a smoothly varying basis for $\Bbb R^n$ and $f\colon I\to\Bbb R^n$ is a smooth function. When you write $f(t) = \sum a_i(t)v_i(t)$, can you give a recipe to find $a_i$ and check that these functions are smooth?

Comment: I guess that my problem is actually why $\tau_t(v_i)'s$ are varying smoothly.  Now that I think about it, it should follow from the smooth variation of the solution of the ODE used to define it.